# Array of Structures in C missing data?

Tags: c

I am designing a program in C. Part of the program involves reading a table of data relating to the periodic table and its elements from a file, and putting it in a structure.

So far, it's working rather well. However, for some reason, when I try to display the array, a couple of elements don't show up, but instead blanks. It does show up earlier in the code, though.

main.c

```
main()
{
    struct periodic *tablePtr;
    tablePtr = createTable();
    printf("%d\t",(tablePtr+90)//Prints "Pa" here as expected
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<num_elements;i++){
        printf("%d\t%s\n",i,(tablePtr+90)->sym);//Prints i, but then just blank.
    }


}
```

periodic.c (creates the table)

```
#include "periodic.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct periodic *createTable(){

    char format[] ="%d\t%s[3]\t \
                         %s[20]\t%f\t \
                         %s[100]\t%f\t \
                         %d\t%f\t%d\t \
                         %d\t%d\t%s[20]\t \
                         %s[7]\t%s[17]\t \
                         %d\t%d\t%f\t \
                         %s[40]\n)";


    struct periodic period_table[num_elements];
    struct periodic *tablePtr = period_table;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("periodictable.csv","r");

    char buff[200];

    struct periodic *initPtr = tablePtr;
    while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp)){
        sscanf(buff,format,&(tablePtr->num),&(tablePtr->sym),&(tablePtr->name),&(tablePtr->weight),&(tablePtr->config),&(tablePtr->neg),&(tablePtr->ion_rad),&(tablePtr->vdW_rad),&(tablePtr->IE_1),&(tablePtr->EA),&(tablePtr->oxi_st),&(tablePtr->stn_st),&(tablePtr->melt),&(tablePtr->boil),&(tablePtr->dens),&(tablePtr->type));
        tablePtr++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return initPtr;

}
```

I can give more information as needed.

Comment: `printf("%d\t",(tablePtr+90)//Prints "Pa" here as expected` how can this print `Pa` if you are telling it to print like a number? Please post the real code. This one wont even compile as you are missing the return type on `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
struct periodic *tablePtr = period_table;
```

Here, `tablePtr` points to an array that is defined locally in the function. And then you return `tablePtr` from the function. When the function returns, the array is destroyed. Hence, the calling function has a dangling pointer.

Referencing a dangling pointer leads to undefined behavior.

You need to allocate memory from the heap, return a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory, and deallocate the memory in the calling function.

```
struct periodic *tablePtr = malloc(sizeof(*tablePtr)*num_elements);
```

and in `main`, call

```
free(tablePtr);
```

before the function ends.

Also, add an explicit return type to `main`.

```
int main() 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! You gave me a clear response that not only gave me a solution but explained why what I had wasn't working. Everything is now working just fine. Thanks again